# Charging caps quick

Tags: capacitor, boost, charging

I'm trying to get some advice on boosting two 7.4v LiPo bats run series (14.8v) to charge two 400v 1500uf caps to 95% in less than 0.0 625sec. The bats I have are for RC application but have the highest output I have been able to find at 65c. The ones I have are 5300mAh but that could be changed if needed. The objective is to pulse an electromagnet 16 times a sec. The final issue its that the components need to be more or less compact. 3"x2"x1" would be the max total size of the charging circuit. I'm pretty new to electronics and this will be the first circuit I am building, so the more info the better.

Comment: Funny you should say RC application, because basically this boils down to calculating RC.  Charging a capacitor to 95% requires, what, four or five RC constants?  So 4RC = 0.063s. You know C, figure our R.  If R is bigger than the resistance in of your charging circuit, you're out of luck as far as hitting that charging time.

Comment: @Kaz 3 time constants is 95.02%. For \$n\$ time constants, \$(1-\frac{1}{e^n})\$ Not that it makes it any more feasible...

Comment: Explaining what you want to achieve in as basic terms as possible, rather than suggesting a solution that you hope may work, is more liable to meet with success. An electomagnet MAY be the best solution or a necessary one, or may not,. But knowing the core application will greatly help with suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

To charge one of your capacitors as specified requires an energy of:

$$ \require{cancel} \begin{align}
W &= \frac{1}{2}CV^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}1500 \mu F (0.95 \cdot 400V)^2 \\
&= \frac {1}{2}0.001500 \frac{J}{\cancel{V^2}} 144400 \cancel{V^2} \\
&= 108.3J
\end{align}$$

You want to do this to two such capacitors, 16 times per second. The required power is then:

$$ 108.3J \cdot 2 \cdot 16/s = 3465.6W $$

That's a lot of power for a couple batteries. Whatever this thing is, it's not going to be small.

If you demanded this power from a 14.8V power source, the current required would be:

$$ 3465.6W / 14.8V \approx 234 A $$

Expressed as a [C-rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29#C_rate), this is:

$$ \frac{234A}{5300mA} = 44.15 $$

This is within the specified capabilities of your batteries, but not by a large margin. Consider that we have thus far assumed that we can convert the battery's energy to the capacitor's energy with 100% efficiency. That's not going to happen in practice.

Say you can convert the power with 80% efficiency:

$$ \begin{align}
P_{out} &= 0.8 \cdot P_{in} \\
3465.6W &= 0.8 P_{in} \\
3465.6W/0.8 &= P_{in} \\
4331.25W &= P_{in}
\end{align} $$

The difference is the power lost to inefficiencies, which will be heat:

$$ P_{loss} = 4331.25W - 3465.6W \approx 856W $$

You are not going to dissipate that much heat in a 3"x2"x1" box. No way. To give you some idea, think of how hot a 100W light bulb gets. Now put 8.5 of them in the same space.

Comment: The EM will be made up of two coils. A 1000 wind copper foil inner coil, and an outer the same but obviously with a larger diameter. The heat thing was something I was anticipating and the space is much larger. I was thinking of liquid cooling. The encasement is aluminum as well for cooling and weight. The mag operates a 4" tool steel rod with an embedded neodymium mag.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I need all the info I can get. Admittedly I'm not up on my theory.

Comment: The the device is a tool btw

Comment: +1 for the analyze, but 80% efficiency is far underestimated. Usually 95..98% is not impossible values nowadays. So, 3500W*0.02 = 70W losses.

Comment: @johnfound impossible? Probably not. Possible without the help of a professional engineer and far more help than can be provided by asking questions on stackexchange? Absolutely.

Comment: I realize this is not something that will be easy to build but I am quite dedicated to this project. I am also very interested in learning all I would need to know to figure and build a circuit like this. I have a few projects that involve circuits like this. Any suggestions for good free online resources to learn electronics?

Comment: @user33348 that sounds like question #2 on the frequent questions.